# Fragment doesn't refresh

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `Fragment` that shows some data saved in android `Preference`.
when these data changes due to various operations of the app, I want to update the fragment with the new data.

I have tried to use

```
myFragmentTransaction.notifyAll();
```

But unfortunately doesn't work and the fragment is updated only when I reopen my whole `Activity`

Houw could I refresh the Fragment on data changes?

Comment: When you change the data, do you commit them? Do you change the value only in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`notifyAll` pertains to threading. Completely unrelated to what you are doing. Instead of trying to tell each fragment to redraw themselves have you tried [OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html). Each fragment should listen to changes in the information they care for.

Comment: thanks for answer. Seem a nice idea using `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`, but I have understood howto use this inside the `Fragment`, could you give me more details?